# Domain Driven Design - Bi Directional association between aggregates

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I've been struggling with modeling something out correctly, the DDD way.

The use case is quite simple. You're a User, and you can be part of a Group. So we have a 1 - many between group and users ( both are aggregates ).

Now, a user should know about it's users , so it contains a list with user ids ( I'm not putting a list of Users in their by purpose ).

But on the other hand, a User should also know in which group he is, so he should have a group id.

The problem here is that we have a bi directional association.

One way I can think to solve this is by not having a group id on the user, but retrieving the group containing the user id.

First of all is this an acceptable solution, if not, could you help me out working away that bi directional relationship ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you look into this article https://refactoring.guru/change-bidirectional-association-to-unidirectional?

Comment: What's the use case of the user knowing which group he belongs to? Is this only for display purposes?

Comment: The term "Knows about" appear in books, its a nice word, but it is not always useful to think of relationships in this way. If you are designing a database, to keep your sanity, think in terms of the ER Modeling - Only! From ER view, a UserGroup Table would not have a userID FK. A User Table must have a UserGroupID FK.

Comment: You may like to re-word "Now, a user should know about it's users ..."

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan yes I did, it's not really in the literal way "how to split a bidirectional", but more how to do it correctly, conceptually :)

Comment: @SubhashBhushan well yes, for disposing purposes, also to retrieve some information around the group, but the user itself will never really take any actions on the group I guess.

Comment: @NoChance Not really sure if I'm OK with that, a group has some business rules around how much users it may have, you could merge 2 groups etc, there is much more functionality related around groups and their user management, then their is around the user interacting with the group.

Comment: When you merge 2 groups, you may decide to create a new group and change the FK in each user to the newly created primary key of the new group. The other ways is to re-use the one of the old groups. In all cases, the FK on the user is used no data is to be kept on the the Group. At least this is the normalized ERD approach in RDBMS. For GUI design, and other purposes, the object model could differ.

Comment: @NoChance I see where you are going, but I wouldn't want to model my domain thinking about how my DB is going to be, to me that's a later problem for the infrastructure part.

I'm not sure whether I'll be using a SQL or a MongoDB, but again, how I model my domain shouldn't be affected by that. But we can still deepen it, just thinking about the model ok ?

Comment: @NoChance So lets say I put my groupId on the User. I retrieve my group aggregate from my repository, how am I suposed to know if my group has reached it's member limit for example ? I'd have to query all the users with that group id, and then check if the amount is hit. I will pull out logic out of my group aggregate then, and have to put it in a service ?

Comment: As per your previous to last comment, in "old" theory you can design your fancy OO model without considering the implementation. I believe this does not work except in books. You must know your database very well to avoid its limitations. As per your last comment, if you are using RDBMS you could Slelct Coun(*) FROM Users Where UserGroupID="004" and get the count. You could also create a db trigger to increase a counter in the Group table.

Comment: @NoChance we should keep in mind that checking the group limit is business logic and belongs in the domain layer, it should not be moved down to a less important layer, the group aggregate should check this in best case. The first thing I stated was that I'm modeling this out with the DDD paradigm in mind, I guess for this case we should stick to this paradigm.

Comment: That is just fine.

Comment: From your domain perspective, what exactly is the problem if a User AR has a GroupId reference and a Group AR has a list of UserIds? Bidirectional associations increase complexity but if it’s necessary for your domain then so be it.

Comment: @RikD well the fact that I've got to maintain them on both sides bugs me a little bit that's it actually. I could just hold a list of user ids on the group part, and then get the group for a user doing a search on groups containing that user id ( a user can only be in one group ). Less performance I guess, so I've to make the tradeof right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial approach is already leading you down a rabbit hole. You are trying to design a **data-model instead of an object-model**. The difference is the data-model models data and the object-model models *behavior*.

There is no "use-case" that a user needs to be a part of a group. The "use-case" is something the end-user does, like printing all groups on a web-ui, listing all users in a group on the web-ui, etc. Those are use-cases.

So I suggest you list all the *behavior* you need, try to assign them to either a `User` or a `Group`. After that you can add the data necessary for those behaviors to the objects.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the answer, after some reflection, my behavior will be around the group ( adding users, removing users, merging 2 groups ), the only time my user needs to know about it's group is when I want to display info of that group, that's not really behavior, so my behavior is located in my Group AR.